# listview selected item not display in dialog box

Tags: android

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private static final String[] lakes = { "Superior","Victoria","Huron","lakhani","sagar","surat","pune","gujarat",
        "baroda","jayesh","mahesh","suresh","chirag","laptop"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lakes);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder abd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    abd.setTitle("selected item");
                    abd.setMessage("selected item is=" + listView.getItemAtPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_DEFAULT));
                    abd.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                    abd.show();
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}




this error diaplay 
Gradle: local variable listView is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

Comment: try to declare listview above onCreate().

Comment: declare listview as a class member and to get the string `String s = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i)`

Comment: change `ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);` to `final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);`. Its because you're accessing local variable inside an anonymous listener and to access a variable inside anonymous definition you should make it to `final`

Comment: run time error display "unfortunately listview1 stopped"

Comment: @sagarlakhani62 can you post the stack trace. If you wish to display it in a toast.`String s = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
       
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
private static final String[] lakes = { "Superior","Victoria","Huron","lakhani","sagar","surat","pune","gujarat",
    "baroda","jayesh","mahesh","suresh","chirag","laptop"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lakes);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                AlertDialog.Builder abd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                abd.setTitle("selected item");
                abd.setMessage("selected item is=" + listView.getItemAtPosition(i));
                abd.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                abd.show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option-
Make listview Globally-

```
 ListView listView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

or make it final

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you change the listview declaration for this:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

or you declare the listview outside the onCreate method.

```
private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your listview as a class member then inside on itemclick

```
        String s = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Use the string to display it in a dialog.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder abd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    abd.setTitle("selected item");
    abd.setMessage("selected item is=" + s);
    abd.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    abd.show();
```

If you wish to display it in a toast.

```
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Scope of the  `ListView listView =
>   (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);` end inside the `onCreate`
>   function.

So Every time when the `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` function is called, your listView object is created and the values are set to it from the function `(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView)`.

> But at the **end of the Function** the **object is dissolved** and you will
>   not be having a variable `listView`anywhere else in the class.

The Problem is solved when you create the variable outside the `onCreate` function and inside the class **MainActivity**

Try to read this for more understanding about the [scope of a variable](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm)

Answer (score 0):

> This should be working

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Object s=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    final String selectedItem=s.toString();
                    AlertDialog.Builder abd = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    abd.setTitle("selected item");
                    abd.setMessage("selected item is=" + selectedItem);
                    abd.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
                    abd.show();
                }
            });
        }
```